# What is the logic behind String [] args in java?

Tags: java

I understand its use,but when they designed java why they did not allow to main
run without `String [] args` (If i, as a programmer, do not need the array)?
there a logic behind the decision?

Comment: Java allows you to overload methods. Under your proposed design, you could have 2 main methods, one which takes an array and one which doesn't. It creates an ambiguity which is tricky to resolve without introducing unnecessary complexity - which one is Java supposed to choose? It is better if there is a single signature for main methods because then there is no ambiguity. If you don't want to take arguments, just ignore the array.

Comment: What would be the purpose of allowing an argument-less `main`? How would it be better than just accepting the `args` and doing nothing with it? More options means more ambiguity and more chances to get stuff wrong. That's acceptable if the benefits are clear and sufficient. I don't think that's the case here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Effectively this question cannot be answered at all unless your name is James Gosling, and I don't think he's particularly active on SO.

No, there is no 'logic' to it, it just is what it is. The main had to take some form. Specifically:

- Java is not structurally typed. Even if I have `interface Camera {void shoot(Person p); }` as well as `interface Gun {void shoot(Person p);}`, even though the structure of a camera and the structure of a gun is identical (they both have a `shoot(Person)` method), you don't just get to treat or even cast a Camera to a Gun or vice versa - java is nominal. Structure doesn't matter.

**Except for main**, which is all about structure. It's inconsistent with itself. No real logic.

- Using a string array is itself weird; arrays, especially of non-primitive types, are best reserved for weird hackery and the core library. They can't grow or shrink, they are not immutable and cannot be made immutable (except zero-len arrays), their toString impl is mostly useless, and their hashCode/equals impls don't do what you wanted them to. `List<String>` would have made more sense.

### But.. WHYY????

Simple:

- `List` wasn't around in java 1.0. There was `java.util.Vector` but that was definitely seen as a bolt-on thing. generics definitely weren't around.
- The idea of using the structural aspect: Have a static method named main that takes a string array - is a straight copy of C. A lot of bizarro java things (such as the syntax for `switch`. Have you looked at it? What the heck, right?) has the explanation: ... because it looks familiar to C programmers. As anachronistic and silly that seems today, java *did* put a real dent in C's dominance, no other language really did that (a bunch, like Python, are older than java and popular too, but python didn't get popular until way later compared to when java got popular. You can make an argument that Perl and PHP did get in C's way a bit, though).

In 'modern' java, you'd have something like:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override public void run (Args args) { ... }
}
```

with a rule that such a thing must have a public no-args constructor.

Given that java started out that way, it doesn't change, in order to keep backwards compatibility. It's not important enough to try to redesign things this way, at least, team OpenJDK doesn't appear to think so.